# Maven Webjars are not found

Tags: java, maven, jersey, embedded-jetty, webjars

I'm trying to use webjars for bootstrap based on their [documentation](https://www.webjars.org/documentation#servlet3)

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

This is how I start the server.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final Server server = createServer();
        try {
            server.start();
            server.join();
        } finally {
            server.destroy();
        }
    }
private static Server createServer() throws Exception {
        final int serverPort = getServerPort();

        final Server server = new Server(serverPort);
        final HandlerList  servletContextHandlers = new HandlerList();
        servletContextHandlers.addHandler(buildServletContextHandler());
        server.setHandler(servletContextHandlers);

        return server;
    }

    private static ServletContextHandler buildServletContextHandler() throws ConfigurationException {
        final ResourceConfig resourceConfig = new ResourceConfig();
        resourceConfig.register(new CustomApiBinder());
        resourceConfig.packages("com.foo.api");

        final ServletHolder servletHolder = new ServletHolder(new ServletContainer(resourceConfig));

        final ServletContextHandler servletContextHandler = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
        servletContextHandler.setContextPath("/api");
        servletContextHandler.addServlet(servletHolder, "/*");

        return servletContextHandler;
    }
```

Then when I try to link the bootstrap css sheet, I get a file not found error

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='webjars/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
```

Do I need a special handler for that? From the documentation, it says that if you use servlet 3, you don't need anything else.

Does anyone have an example **without** using Spring?

Jetty 9.4.9.v20180320

Jersey 2.26

Comment: Are the webjars/bootstrap using `META-INF/resources` directories? Also, where is your base resource path declaration for the `ServletContextHandler` in your code example?

Comment: What do you mean by webjars/boostrap using META-INF/resouces? There's nothing in this directory. I thought maven would copy the resources in there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `bootstrap-<ver>.jar` has a `META-INF/resources/` subdirectory.

```
$ jar -tvf bootstrap-4.0.0.jar | grep META-INF/resources
     0 Thu Jan 18 21:20:32 GMT 2018 META-INF/resources/
     0 Thu Jan 18 21:20:32 GMT 2018 META-INF/resources/webjars/
     0 Thu Jan 18 21:20:32 GMT 2018 META-INF/resources/webjars/bootstrap/
     0 Thu Jan 18 21:20:38 GMT 2018 META-INF/resources/webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0/
     0 Thu Jan 18 21:20:38 GMT 2018 META-INF/resources/webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/
     0 Thu Jan 18 21:20:38 GMT 2018 META-INF/resources/webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/
 43852 Thu Jan 18 21:20:38 GMT 2018 META-INF/resources/webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap-grid-jsf.css
  4076 Thu Jan 18 21:20:38 GMT 2018 META-INF/resources/webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap-grid-jsf.css.gz
 43852 Thu Jan 18 11:29:48 GMT 2018 META-INF/resources/webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap-grid.css
  4076 Thu Jan 18 21:20:38 GMT 2018 META-INF/resources/webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap-grid.css.gz
 95910 Thu Jan 18 11:29:48 GMT 2018 META-INF/resources/webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap-grid.css.map
 34243 Thu Jan 18 21:20:38 GMT 2018 META-INF/resources/webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap-grid.min-jsf.css
  3483 Thu Jan 18 21:20:38 GMT 2018 META-INF/resources/webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap-grid.min-jsf.css.gz
 34243 Thu Jan 18 11:29:48 GMT 2018 META-INF/resources/webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css
  3483 Thu Jan 18 21:20:38 GMT 2018 META-INF/resources/webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css.gz
 76209 Thu Jan 18 11:29:48 GMT 2018 META-INF/resources/webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css.map
178152 Thu Jan 18 21:20:38 GMT 2018 META-INF/resources/webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap-jsf.css
 22410 Thu Jan 18 21:20:38 GMT 2018 META-INF/resources/webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap-jsf.css.gz
  4798 Thu Jan 18 21:20:38 GMT 2018 META-INF/resources/webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap-reboot-jsf.css
  1683 Thu Jan 18 21:20:38 GMT 2018 META-INF/resources/webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap-reboot-jsf.css.gz
  4798 Thu Jan 18 11:29:48 GMT 2018 META-INF/resources/webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap-reboot.css
  1683 Thu Jan 18 21:20:38 GMT 2018 META-INF/resources/webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap-reboot.css.gz
 57721 Thu Jan 18 11:29:48 GMT 2018 META-INF/resources/webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap-reboot.css.map
  3936 Thu Jan 18 21:20:38 GMT 2018 META-INF/resources/webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap-reboot.min-jsf.css
  1584 Thu Jan 18 21:20:38 GMT 2018 META-INF/resources/webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap-reboot.min-jsf.css.gz
  3936 Thu Jan 18 11:29:48 GMT 2018 META-INF/resources/webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap-reboot.min.css
  1584 Thu Jan 18 21:20:38 GMT 2018 META-INF/resources/webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap-reboot.min.css.gz
 25881 Thu Jan 18 11:29:48 GMT 2018 META-INF/resources/webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap-reboot.min.css.map
178152 Thu Jan 18 11:29:48 GMT 2018 META-INF/resources/webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.css
 22410 Thu Jan 18 21:20:38 GMT 2018 META-INF/resources/webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.css.gz
411645 Thu Jan 18 11:29:48 GMT 2018 META-INF/resources/webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.css.map
144877 Thu Jan 18 21:20:38 GMT 2018 META-INF/resources/webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min-jsf.css
 20563 Thu Jan 18 21:20:38 GMT 2018 META-INF/resources/webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min-jsf.css.gz
144877 Thu Jan 18 11:29:48 GMT 2018 META-INF/resources/webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css
 20563 Thu Jan 18 21:20:38 GMT 2018 META-INF/resources/webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css.gz
551641 Thu Jan 18 11:29:48 GMT 2018 META-INF/resources/webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css.map
195855 Thu Jan 18 11:29:48 GMT 2018 META-INF/resources/webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.js
 41578 Thu Jan 18 21:20:38 GMT 2018 META-INF/resources/webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.js.gz
326634 Thu Jan 18 11:29:48 GMT 2018 META-INF/resources/webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.js.map
 67742 Thu Jan 18 11:29:48 GMT 2018 META-INF/resources/webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js
 19244 Thu Jan 18 21:20:38 GMT 2018 META-INF/resources/webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js.gz
273872 Thu Jan 18 11:29:48 GMT 2018 META-INF/resources/webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js.map
115048 Thu Jan 18 11:29:48 GMT 2018 META-INF/resources/webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.js
 20137 Thu Jan 18 21:20:38 GMT 2018 META-INF/resources/webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.js.gz
195373 Thu Jan 18 11:29:48 GMT 2018 META-INF/resources/webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.js.map
 48944 Thu Jan 18 11:29:48 GMT 2018 META-INF/resources/webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js
 13105 Thu Jan 18 21:20:38 GMT 2018 META-INF/resources/webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js.gz
161998 Thu Jan 18 11:29:48 GMT 2018 META-INF/resources/webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js.map
   284 Thu Jan 18 21:20:32 GMT 2018 META-INF/resources/webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0/webjars-requirejs.js
   182 Thu Jan 18 21:20:38 GMT 2018 META-INF/resources/webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0/webjars-requirejs.js.gz
```

This kind of JAR is a web resource jar, and for Jetty it's only available when using a full blown `WebAppContext`.

> Note: When using a Jetty `WebAppContext` all of the `WEB-INF/lib/*.jar!/META-INF/resources/` contents will be unpacked into a temporary directory so that Jetty can serve the contents of those special jar files.

You have a few options from here (ordered from best/easiest choice to most complex).

1. Have maven unpack your `META-INF/resources` jars into your resources directory, that you then reference by classpath resource URL as the `ServletContextHandler` resource base location.
2. Have your own code unpack the `META-INF/resources` directories into a temporary directory that you then use as a the `ServletContextHandler` resource base directory.
3. Change over to using a full blown `WebAppContext` with a `war` file and all of the extra configuration necessary to enable the various features you want to use.

Note, if your eventual end goal is [to build a jetty uber jar](https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-uber-jar), then option 1 will be the best choice overall.

The choice you make will depend on how you eventually want to package your project up.

- Will it be 1 self executing jar?  Then option 1.
- Will it be a collection of jars? Then options 1 and 2 are good choices.
- Will it be a collection of jars and a war file?  Then option 3 is a good choice.

The biggest issue with `META-INF/resources` based content is name collision resolution.  Because of this, I encourage you to go with option 1 as this will resolve (at build time) any conflict resolution issues.

Eg: If you have 2 JAR files, both with `META-INF/resources/foo.css` file (but with different contents) and a request arrives for `http://<host>/foo.css`, which one do you serve?

For an example of Option 1 see - https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-with-web-resources

Some embedded-jetty resources maintained by the Eclipse Jetty project:

- https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/embedding-jetty.html
- https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-cookbook
- https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/tree/jetty-9.4.9.v20180320/examples/embedded/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you have any resources about how to setup a embedded WebAppContect for an embedded server? Do I need a web.xml?

Comment: Also it's asking me to set a war for the context

Comment: updated answer with links to embedded-jetty documentation and examples

Comment: Im a little bit confused. Why do we need to specify a war? Is it not what's going to be built?

Comment: like the answer says, the whole `META-INF/resources` concept is for war files (aka `WebAppContext`).  You can get around that requirement by doing the work that `WebAppContext` would have done for you during build time using Options 1 or 2 in the answer.  Choosing to use a war is the hardest/most difficult/most work option (as was also pointed out in the answer)

Comment: Ah sorry I misunderstood

Comment: I went ahead and prepared an example for you, see "example of option 1" in answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add a `ResourceHandler` like:

```
ResourceHandler resourceHandler = new ResourceHandler();
resourceHandler.setDirectoriesListed(false);
resourceHandler.setResourceBase(Main.class.getResource("META-INF/resources/webjars").toExternalForm());

ContextHandler webJarContext = new ContextHandler();
webJarContext.setContextPath("/webjars");
webJarContext.setHandler(resourceHandler);
```

Comment: That will only work for the first `META-INF/resources/webjars` classpath entry.  Not the others.

Answer (score 0):

As Joakim Erdfelt suggested, I use maven to copy the resources into the target classes.

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                        <id>unpack</id>
                        <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>unpack</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>swagger-ui</artifactId>
                                    <version>${swagger-ui.version}</version>                                    
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                    <includes>META-INF/resources/webjars/**/*</includes>
                                    <excludes>META-INF/resources/webjars/**/*index.html</excludes>
                                    <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/target/classes/</outputDirectory>
                                    </artifactItem>
                                </artifactItems>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>   
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: The example project does something similar - https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-with-web-resources

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time of writing an example. It works very well.